# Rails using byebug inside a proc?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, byebug

I am trying to use byebug/debugger inside a proc that gets called later with threads, but its not working. So how can I Debug code inside a proc?

Comment: take a look at the section on threads [here](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/master/GUIDE.md)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to ensure that the thread inside which you are adding the breakpoint eventually calls `join`.

e.g.:

```
myproc = Proc.new do
  Thread.new do
    require 'pry'; binding.pry
  end.join
end

myproc.call
```

**will** stop at the breakpoint.

Whereas

```
myproc = Proc.new do
  Thread.new do
    require 'pry'; binding.pry
  end
end

myproc.call
```

**will not**